# UIWebView and File Mime Types

Tags: ios, ios6

I have a `UIWebView` that downloads files (PDF, Word, Excel) from a web server requiring authentication. To do this I have handled the authentication and populated a `NSMutableData` Object as per the Apple recommendations.

When loading the data into the `UIWebView` I don't want to hardcode the Mime Type, any ideas on how to avoid this?

```
[_webView loadData:data MimeType: @"application/msword" textEncodingName: @"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @""]];
```

Tried the below but always get "text/html" returned:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didRecieveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
    NSString *mimeType = [httpResponse MIMEType];
    NSLog(@"MIMETYPE: %@",mimeType);
}
```

Response headers are here:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 50176
Content-Type: application/msword
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.doc
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

**EDIT:**
Something odd is going is happening with the headers.

The headers I originally posted were verified in Chrome and Fiddler2 but the NSURLConnection is actually receiving:

> "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=us-ascii,application/msword"; 
>   "Content-Length" = "341, 79360";

The below snippet was used to confirm this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didRecieveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];
    NSLog([dictionary description]);
    }
}
```

Any idea why it's receiving this invalid header, I'm stumped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps someone else I couldn't find an answer as to why IIS is producing that particular header, have had to code a small parser for the headers so it ignores text/html in the presence of an application/ header.

Answer (score 0):

Use the

```
[[httpReponse allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Content-Type"] isEqualToString:@"application/msword"]
```

to check the response header.

May be you are missing the fact that multiple redirection occours during the request.

Comment: Seems like it should work but this isn't working: NSString mimeType= [[httpResponse allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"content-type"] stringValue];

Comment: Well you should be getting redirects, I think. Please check responses in your    **- (NSURLRequest*)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response**  method. didReceiveResponse only called when there is a response send from the server, there after other delegate methods take charge of the program flow.

Answer (score 0):

my way around to avoid mime types: in connectionDidFinishLoading

```
[webView loadHTMLString:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] baseURL:[[connection currentRequest] URL]];
```